# How to prevent the Menu to close when clicking somewhere out of its bounds

Tags: wpf, menu

When I open the menu, and after that click somewhere in the window the menu is closing, how can I prevent it from being closed ?

this is my XAML-

```
<Grid>
    <Menu Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Menu.Items>
            <MenuItem Header="file">
                <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu.Items>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt that most user would like this...

Comment: @H.B - Tell that to my team leader.
but to be serious, this is good thing but I can't detail all the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to re-template the `Menu` control so that its `Popup` has `StaysOpen="true"`. I don't believe `Menu` exposes any property that its template binds to in order to allow you to control this without the need for re-templating. Alternatively, you could hack together a solution that searches for the `Popup` in the visual tree and injects the desired property value.

But, really, I think you should think about alternative solutions altogether. This is a pretty radical departure from the normal expected behavior of menus, and such a radical departure would require radical impetus.

Comment: Thanks Kent, unfortunately it did not work for me.
I've copied the menuItem default template from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.85).aspx
and set StaysOpen="true" just like you said.